# If $\frac {9\sin x-3\cos x}{2\sin x + \cos x}=2$, define $\tan x$ and angle $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If: $$\frac {9\sin x-3\cos x}{2\sin x + \cos x}=2$$ $(0^\circ < x < 90^\circ$), define $\tan x$ and angle $x$.

Because of this in the parenthesis I know that I have to use some relation between complementary angles ex. $3\cos x = 3\sin(90^\circ-x)$ but when I include that in my problem I don't see any progress? I also don't really know what to do with the $2$ on the RHS. Any hints?

Comment: multiply both sides by $(2\sin x + \cos x)$ to eliminate the fraction.  Collect the $\sin x$ terms on one side and the $\cos x$ terms on the other.  Divide through by $\cos x$

Comment: I encourage you to accept an answer, the one which satisfies you most. I am no way saying that it should be mine but you accept an answer which you like (well it can be mine also :-P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Divide numerator and denominator in LHS by $\cos x$.

Once you get $\tan x$ take $\arctan$ to get $x$.

Comment: Thanks! Is $\tan x = -\frac{3}{5}$ ?

Comment: @RiktasMath    No it is 1 I think

Comment: Oops. It is indeed 1. Thanks!

Comment: @RiktasMath my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

from the given equation we get
$$9\sin(x)-3\cos(x)=4\sin(x)+2\cos(x)$$
and from here
$$5\sin(x)=5\cos(x)$$
therefore $$\tan(x)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \frac {9\sin x-3\cos x}{2\sin x + \cos x}=2 \\[10pt]
\text{Therefore } & \frac{9\tan x - 3}{2\tan x + 1} = 2 \\[10pt]
& \text{and so on.}
\end{align}